# Send data from POS to API

Tags: api, payment, payment-processing, point-of-sale, pos

I am trying to build I tool which will collect all the transactions made by a POS. I dont really know how to get started so I will comment what I am trying to reach and what I have thought already.

**Goal**: get the transactions data outside a POS.

**Ideas**:

- build an API which will receive requests from the POS. This would means that I also have to build a software which will interact with my POS to send a POST request to my API (I think)
- more ideas...

Since I dont really know how POS software works I am a bit blind in this topic. I would need someone to guide me in these or new ideas, or at least tell me if this is even possible.

Thank You!